# Get full path of a running process and save it to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I want to get the full path of a running process and save it to a variable.
Let's say I want to get the full path to a file called notepad.exe.

I tried to search for the solution, but I didn't find any.
I think that it can be done with the tasklist command or something similar..
I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you test this `For /F %b in ('"where cmd.exe"') do set a=%b` put path of cmd in a variable

Comment: It won't get the full path to my file.
I get this: "C:\Users\tom\Desktop\Pixel"
instead of this: "C:\Users\tom\Desktop\Pixel Warfare 2"

Comment: Oh I actually found it out!
`for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d "Player.exe"') do set a=%%i`
that worked for me.
But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the executable you're testing for is in your `%PATH%`, the simplest solution is to use the `~$PATH` expansion of a `for` loop.  (In a console window, `help for` for full details.)

```js
for %%I in (notepad.exe) do set "exepath=%%~$PATH:I"

echo %exepath%
```

If you need to get the path directly from the process, you can do it with `wmic`.

```js
wmic process where "name='notepad.exe'" get ExecutablePath
```

You can capture the result to a variable with a `for /f` loop.  WMI query results are often encoded in a weird encoding (UCS-2 Little Endian, if I recall correctly), so it helps to query a throwaway column to prevent oddness in the capture.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in (
    'wmic process where "name='notepad.exe'" get ExecutablePath^,Handle /format:csv ^| find /i "notepad.exe"'
) do set "exepath=%%~I"

echo %exepath%
```

Comment: This answer has no guarantee of returning a populated executable path for running processes. It's not for what I'm checking against.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about DOS command but you can try `Get-WmiObject` powerShell commandlet like below

```
(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Process -Filter 'Name="notepad.exe"').path.SubString(0, (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Process -Filter 'Name="notepad.exe"').path.LastIndexOf('\'))
```

This will return result

```
C:\Windows\system32
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want this in powershell we can do it

```
$a=( Get-Process -ProcessName * | Format-List path )
```

get all path in $a
just do in cmd

```
powershell -command Get-Process -ProcessName * ^| Format-List path
```